# I failed to access HTTPS's WMS service using PyQGIS's QgsRasterLayer

Tags: python, gis, qgis, wms, pyqgis

```
uri = '''https://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0?LAYERS=basic&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&STYLES=&FORMAT=image%2Fjpeg&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&BBOX=-90,45,-45,90&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256 '''
layer = QgsRasterLayer(uri, "RESA", "WMS")
if layer.isValid():
    pass
else:
    print('error')
```

The result is 'error'.This does not meet my expectations of adding an HTTPS type WMS service.I tried querying pyQGIS's API, but found nothing.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Note that you are using `QgsVectorLayer` specifying WFS as the data provider to fetch a **raster** WMS layer. Do you know the difference between WFS and WMS?

Comment: sorry!  The question is error.I change it at now.

Comment: I am a python engineer.The basic concepts of GIS are not well understood,However, there is no problem with the scenario I asked, that is, how to use pyQGIS API to call the image data adding WMS class, and the protocol type is HTTPS, we call HTTP without problem

Comment: To display a WMS layer you need to instantiate a QgsRasterLayer.

Comment: i change my question and add some pictures to explain my dilemma.

Comment: Checkout this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/152767/7086). Perhaps you would get help faster on the GIS Stackexchange site.

Comment: Also note that [posting screenshots of the code is discouraged on this site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).